# SCSS: If statement inside a css rule

Tags: sass

Is it possible to add sass if statements inside a css rule?  To avoid repetition. I tried this, but sass complains about syntax.

```
@mixin outline($color, $shadow:'none') {

    text-shadow: 
        1px 0 0 $color,
        0 1px 0 $color, 
        0 -1px 0 $color, 
        -1px 0 0 $color

        @if $shadow != 'none' {
            , $shadow
        }
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array to store all shadows and then append `$shadow` if conditional statement is true

```
@mixin outline($color, $shadow: false) {
  $shadows: (
    1px 0 0 $color,
    0 1px 0 $color, 
    0 -1px 0 $color, 
    -1px 0 0 $color);

  @if $shadow {
    $shadows: append($shadows, $shadow);
  }
  text-shadow: $shadows;
}
```

Check out the [SASS append function reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#append-instance_method)